# Get a filename from a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have this strings  saved in my mysql database in format like:

```
/uploads/attachments/18/105/WordPress_3_Cookbook.pdf
```

Now, I need to get only the file name.

I guess I need some function in PHP that check the string from the backwards and get everything to the first slash.

How to write such thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) this way

```
$filename = basename("/uploads/attachments/18/105/WordPress_3_Cookbook.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If you don't want to type all the link path inside the "basename()" function, you can use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

this will return the whole path - (example below)

```
"/uploads/attachments/18/105/WordPress_3_Cookbook.pdf"
```

2.THEN make use of the 'baseline()' function like this:

```
      echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

and will return the desired file name as a string.

```
      // the output will be : WordPress_3_Cookbook.pdf
```